# Error. La conversión especificada no es válida

Tags: c#, asp.net

Tengo un Gridview en ASP .NET en el cual totalizo las columnas, pero solo en una me lanza error:

```html
decimal totalConvertidas = dt.AsEnumerable().Sum(row => row["Convertidas"] == DBNull.Value ? 0 : row.Field<decimal>("Convertidas"));
GridView1.FooterRow.Cells[14].Text=totalConvertidas.ToString("N0");
GridView1.Columns[14].ItemStyle.HorizontalAlign=HorizontalAlign.Center;
```

Para totalizar las demás columnas uso la misma sintaxis pero solo en esta me dice:"La conversión especificada no es válida"
Los datos que debe sumar son los siguientes: 
Y como verán algunos son numeros enteros y algunos tienen decimales, nose si eso cause el error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrias aplicar un poco mas de logica en la conversion de tipos

```
decimal totalConvertidas = dt.AsEnumerable()
                            .Sum(row => 
                                {
                                    decimal result = 0.0m;

                                    if(row["Convertidas"] != DBNull.Value)
                                    {
                                        decimal.TryParse(row["Convertidas"].ToString(), out result);
                                    }

                                    return result;
                                });
```

al usar el `decimal.TryParse()` si el vlaor numerico no es valido no fallara

Ahora bien puede deberse tambien a la cultura aplicada

```
var culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("es-ES");
var style = NumberStyles.None;
decimal.TryParse(row["Convertidas"].ToString(), style, culture, out result);
```

tambien podrias ver de usar el `decimal.Parse()` indicnado la cultura